# How to place a sidebar with all category in opencart

Tags: php, model-view-controller, opencart2.x

Can anyone please explain the steps for creating a sidebar and place it in all pages in opencart.

I am new to opencart. My opencart version is 2.3.0.2

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use "**Category**" module for that.

1. Go to admin > Extension > Extension > Module > Install & Enable **Category** module.
2. Go to admin > Design > Layout > Home(which you want page.) > & then Add Category module in **Left Column** > then Save.